# Error en una igualación

Tags: c

soy nuevo en C y tengo el siguiente problema, tengo que ordenar alfabeticamente un vector tipo struct, pero en el burbujeo tengo dos errores:

```
error: expected identifier or '(' before '=' token  
error: expected expression before 'tmp'
```

```
#define nom 30
#define cant 3

typedef struct {

  char nombre[nom];
  int id;
} pasajeros;

void burbuja(pasajeros pasajero[cant]) {

  int TAM = 20;

  typedef pasajeros tmp;

  for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < TAM; j++) {
      if (strcmp(pasajero[j].nombre, pasajero[i].nombre) > 0) {
        tmp = pasajero[j]; // < -Error 1 pasajero[j] = pasajero[i];
        pasajero[i] = tmp; // < -Error 2
      }
    }
  }
  printf("\nPasajeros Ordenados Alfabeticamente(A-Z)\n\n");
}
```

Comment: `typedef pasajeros tmp;` Porque tienes un `typedef` ahi? Esa es la causa del error, borralo.

Answer (score 1):

En [c](/questions/tagged/c) las estructuras son tipos son datos compuestos, a diferencia de los tipos "*normales*" como pudieran ser `char` o `int` necesitas explicitar que estás trabajando con una estructura para darle uso:

```
struct S {}; // Declaramos una estructura.

struct S s;  // Creamos una instancia de la estructura.
```

El anteponer `struct` ante las declaraciones es engorroso, así que habitualmente se crea un alias de tipo para referirnos a las estructuras, el alias de tipo se crea con la instrucción `typedef` (*`type` `def`inition* o definición de tipo); de esta manera es menos engorroso usar las estructuras:

```
// Declaramos una estructura anónima y le asignamos el alias 'S'
typedef struct {} S;

S s;  // Creamos una instancia de la estructura.
```

No es necesario que la estructura sea anónima:

```
// Declaramos la estructura 'struct S' y le asignamos el alias 'S'
typedef struct S {} S;

S s;  // Creamos una instancia de la estructura.
```

En resumen, la instrucción `typedef` asigna a un tipo una definición:

```
   typedef struct S {} S;
// ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^    ^
//   \       \          \____________ para que sea 'S'
//    \       \___________ 'struct S'
//     \____Define el tipo
```

---

Ahora que entendemos el comportamiento de `typedef`, veamos qué ha pasado con esta instrucción:

```
typedef pasajeros tmp;
```

Le estás diciendo al compilador que el tipo `pasajeros` tendrá el alias `tmp`, así que desde ese momento puedes referirte a esta estructura anónima:

```
struct {
  char nombre[nom];
  int id;
};
```

Como `pasajeros` o como `tmp`. Eso no es incorrecto, lo que es incorrecto es usar un tipo (`tmp`) como si fuese una instancia:

```
   tmp = pasajero[j]; // < -Error 1 pasajero[j] = pasajero[i];
// ^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^ 
//  \__Tipo     \__Instancia
   pasajero[i] = tmp; // < -Error 2
// ^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^
//  \__Instancia   \__Tipo
```

Lo que en realidad querías hacer es esto:

```
pasajeros tmp; // No estás definiendo un tipo, estás creando una instancia.
```